# Ember.RSVP.Promise with sync

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

Is it possible to pass async as false for Ember.RSVP.Promise ?

```
var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
return $.ajax({
    url: requestUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON', 
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(postData)
}).success(resolve).error(reject);
```

I mean similar to how we can set when using Ember.$.ajax

```
var ajaxReq = Ember.$.ajax({
    url: "/someService",
    data: data,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

Comment: Can you detail the requirement a bit ?

Comment: I just wanted to know if I can make a sync request using Ember.RSVP.Promise

Comment: Yeah i got that.. but can you detail the complete premises of that requirement.. i mean by sync, you necessarily need the response before moving ahead with the execution. We can achieve that using deffered execution.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need...i.e. sync execution of Ember Promise...when I use promise.then() in my code

Comment: maybe ES7 async/await can help http://mockra.com/2016/01/13/emberjs-es7-async/ ?

Answer (score 0):

No!
A Promise can not be executed in sync! This is a javascript limitation.

And you replay don't want this because you have just one Thread. So blocking that Thread would block everything!

A Promise is also not only about AJAX!